# InfraRed Remote Control stopped working

Tags: 12.04, hardware, remote-control

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and my Compro K100 worked fine in the beginning. But somewhere along the way it has stopped working. Who can help me diagnose the problem?

To start off here is some info.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 185b:3082 Compro K100 Infrared Receiver v2
```

`dmesg | grep compro`:

```
[   12.992886] mceusb 2-1.4:1.0: Registered Compro VideoMate IR with mce emulator interface version 1  
[ 2468.755328] mceusb 2-1.2:1.0: Registered Compro VideoMate IR with mce emulator interface version 1
```

`dmesg | grep usb`:

```
[    1.641739] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs  
[    1.641748] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub  
[    1.641768] usbcore: registered new device driver usb  
[    2.352920] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual  
[    2.644360] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd  
[    2.887996] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd  
[    3.091819] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd  
[    3.639003] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd  
[    3.802762] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd  
[    3.898544] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0  
[    3.898595] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage  
[    3.966517] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd  
[    4.059965] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0  
[    4.130275] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd  
[    4.293976] usb 2-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd 
[    4.412784] usb 2-1.8: config 0 descriptor??  
[    4.509855] usb 2-1.1.1: new low-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd  
[    4.627949] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1.1/2-1.1.1:1.0/input/input5  
[    4.628042] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01B.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse   [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.1/input0  
[    4.628057] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid  
[    4.628059] usbhid: USB HID core driver  
[    4.709412] usb 2-1.1.2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd  
[    4.828284] input: Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1.2/2-1.1.2:1.0/input/input6  
[    4.828426] generic-usb 0003:046D:C316.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard   [Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.2/input0  
[    4.835006] input: Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1.2/2-1.1.2:1.1/input/input7  
[    4.835236] generic-usb 0003:046D:C316.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device   [Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1.2/input1  
[   12.801271] input: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (185b:3082) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/rc/rc0/input9  
[   12.801320] rc0: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (185b:3082) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/rc/rc0  
[   12.921244] input: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input10  
[   12.921369] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo  
[   12.992886] mceusb 2-1.4:1.0: Registered Compro VideoMate IR with mce emulator interface version 1  
[   12.992896] mceusb 2-1.4:1.0: 2 tx ports (0x0 cabled) and 2 rx sensors (0x0 active)  
[   12.992931] usbcore: registered new interface driver mceusb  
[   13.584509] input: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb) as /devices/virtual/input/input11  
[   13.605165] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (mceusb) registered at minor = 0  
[ 1881.898680] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 6  
[ 1898.456785] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd  
[ 1898.560247] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.1  
[ 1961.140680] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 10  
[ 1961.850500] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd  
[ 1961.952297] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.1  
[ 1962.674182] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 13  
[ 1962.872947] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd  
[ 1962.977036] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.1  
[ 1963.185342] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 14   
[ 1963.895426] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci_hcd  
[ 1963.998828] scsi11 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.1  
[ 2459.249660] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4  
[ 2468.228341] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci_hcd  
[ 2468.562431] input: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (185b:3082) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/rc/rc1/input22  
[ 2468.562588] rc1: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (185b:3082) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/rc/rc1  
[ 2468.562850] input: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb) as /devices/virtual/input/input23  
[ 2468.564473] rc rc1: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (mceusb) registered at minor = 0  
[ 2468.755328] mceusb 2-1.2:1.0: Registered Compro VideoMate IR with mce emulator interface version 1  
[ 2468.755339] mceusb 2-1.2:1.0: 2 tx ports (0x0 cabled) and 2 rx sensors (0x0 active)
```

`lsmod | grep usb`:

```
mceusb                 18143  0   
rc_core                26412  10  ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,mceusb  
usbhid                 47199  0   
hid                    99592  1 usbhid  
usb_storage            49198  2
```

What else can I run to get insight as to why this device stopped working?

Comment: What stopped working? When you power on the device, nothing at all happens?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Using the same remote K100 videomate.

Not sure if this will help you, but I've read up and it seems that the problems started after a certain kernel upgrade... You can always try rolling back to a previous kernel and see if that works, but I would not recommend it.

In the end, I ended up using my Genius Gamepad together with JJK (Java Joypad to Keyboard mapper) to act as a remote. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12405868

However, not sure if this is a solution/workaround that you can use.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to attempt to either roll back or upgrade the kernel. I will post the results.